# Save agent location in a "seize" block and use location in a "move-to" block

Tags: location, anylogic, agent

My model is a basic warehouse situation model. Trucks enter the model, are seized by an empty loading dock resource and then offloaded by the forklifts. The trucks location (loading bay 1, loading bay 2 etc.) is determined by the available resource that gets seized. My "move-to" block then has the "move to location of seized resource" option ticked. In this case, the truck half of the model is working as expected.

The forklift half is a little harder. I have been advised to inject pallet agents into the model instead of splitting them off the incoming trucks. The problem is that I can't specify the location of the agents to a specific resource.

How can I save the location of the newly parked truck (loading bay 1, loading bay 2 etc.) in a variable, and then call on that same variable to inject the agents into that location? The nodes that are acting as the loading bays, are the home locations of specific resources (loading bays).

When I save the location (varAgentLocation = getNetworkNode();) I have to set the variable type to type "custom" (INode) to void errors. The if I type "varAgentLocation" in the location box of the source, I get an error stating that the types are not the same (INode and InitialLocationType)

Comment: What object types are your loading bays? Use that as the type for your variable and instantiate when your trucks arrive there and create pallet agents...

Comment: What do you mean object type? It is just a resource pool. My trucks and pallets are agents.

Comment: If they are ResourcePools, set the variable type to ResourcePool (choose "Other" and type it with code-complete)

Answer (score 0):

Using home locations for your (non-moving) loading bay resources is unnecessary.

Just have them as custom resource agent types (e.g., agent type `LoadingBay`, not vanilla `Agent`) with a type `Node` parameter that you set at model startup to be the relevant space markup nodes. (You need to have the resource pool add the resource agents to a custom (initially empty) population of `LoadingBay`s you've created beforehand; this allows you then to loop through the resource agents at model startup to setup any parameters, etc. for them.)

Then probably the most coherent way is to

- Copy this value into a variable within your `Truck` agent via the on-seize action of your `Seize` block.
- Have your `Pallet` agents created with a reference to the `Truck` agent they came from (in a variable or parameter). There are various design alternatives for whether the pallets exist beforehand (where you might use an `Unbatch` block to 'release' them) or whether you create them on the fly.
- When you inject pallet agents into, say, a `Source` block, set that to have the arrival node (which can be a dynamic expression) getting the relevant node from the 'parent' Truck agent (e.g., something like `agent.arrivalTruck.loadingBayNode`).

Comment: Best answer ever! Thanks Stuart!

Comment: Just to elaborate further, let's say i have a population of resources, how would you loop through them and check things like whether they're available and what their position is? Where would these commands be placed to ensure that the loop is constantly being called on?

Comment: Just loop via a standard Java foreach loop (e.g., `for (LoadingBay bay : popLoadingBays) { // Do stuff }`. In this case you only need loop once at model startup; not sure where  you think that a loop would need to "constantly being called on"?